# Case sensitive URL's with NextJS 10 problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In the latest few release of NextJS, the router has become case sensitive. I've been slowly re-writing our conference web site with NextJS and I've noticed that much of our valued SEO is stored by google and others as cased and will cause 404's.

For example, this URL is discoverable by googling "Douglas Crockford Silicon Valley Code Camp".

https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Session/2018/qa-with-douglas-crockford

Is there a way with NextJS, when running in production to somehow lowercase all incoming URL's, even as some kind of redirect?

I'm following the pattern they have here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes and my app is using GetStaticPaths, as I plan to use ISR (incremental static regen) so it needs to work with that also.

Also, since the site has always been case insensitive, URL's are stored in various ways so I can't just make it to what Google stores it as.

Comment: The real problem I had here is that I have URL's like https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/Session/2018/QA-With-Douglas-Crockford that need to be lowercased. I ended up solving this by creating a second docker container as a proxy and then updating everything that goes through the proxy to lower case.  I found no way to  do this with NextJS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you have something like that: /articles/:slug. I would get the slug using the router and then create a hook at mount time to redirect to "/articles/:lowercaseSlug" if slug has any capital letters.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter;
const { slug } = router.query;

useEffect(() => {
    if (slug.toLowerCase() !== slug) // Check if it has any capital letters
        router.push(`/articles/${slug.toLowerCase()}`) // Redirect to the working path
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai, I'll give this a try later. Sounds like exactly what I need for my dynamic routes.  However, what about routes that are not dynamic like just /pages/about.js where I want /About and /about to work the same?

Comment: In that case, I would use next js redirects from here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects where source is "/About" and destination is "/about"